# Changing function paramter vs assigning a new variable

Tags: java, function, design-patterns

In the following code snippet, i have introduced another variable called `k`, to start with value provided by `starIndex`. However, it is unnecessary, as bcoz we all know, its a pass by value.
But I can see pro's and con's of both approaches.

1. Change the function parameter value: If I modify the value of `starIndex` instead of using `k`, then `starIndex` is no longer the indexof star char, in essence it lost its meaning. This would be confusing if the function was too long.
2. Introducing `k` : overhead / headache of assigning of managing a new variable.

`To make question generic, what is preferred ? A new variable ? or reusing the function params and modifying their value ?`

```
   private static int getNonStarIndex(String regex, int starIndex) {  
        for (int k = starIndex + 1; k < regex.length(); k++) {
            if (regex.charAt(k) != '*') {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return regex.length();
    }
```

Comment: This is a case by case problem. In yours, you don't need `k`.

Comment: What is this method trying to do?  I would be interested to hear its purpose there may be an easier way to do this.

Comment: @KevinBowersox http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35552/regex-parser-request-for-review-and-optimization?noredirect=1#comment57676_35552

Comment: So you want to find the index of the first character that is not a `*` after the first `*`?  Why do you pass in the `starIndex`?  Should that be `startIndex`? And will `starIndex` or `startIndex` always be the index of the first `*`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but can we focus on the main question asked ?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred solution is to trust the compiler to make the underlying code efficient, and focus on Java code readability. Keep your 'k' and make the starIndex parameter final to make it clear in the signature what you are doing.

EDIT: 
The argument for both choices (keeping k and making starIndex final) is the principle of least surprise.

Imagine that you did drop k and re-used the starIndex parameter instead. This makes the next guy who is reading the code wonder if you are aware that this change is purely local, or if you did in fact expect this to change the value of starIndex at the call point.

By making the starIndex parameter "final" you make it quite clear what you are doing, and that you intend to do it in exactly this way.